# Can't access nesting JSON result from fetch react app

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, fetch

I have really stuck in the part, I've been working on react app, when they click the tab/button, will fetch more result to come back, and I try to map through it to display. but keep showing undefined.

I see the result in my console, but each time I try to access the result, it comeback empty or error `undefined`

[Here's my full code](https://codesandbox.io/s/quizzical-meadow-oxi88?fontsize=14)

```
componentDidMount() {
    const results = fetch("https://api.github.com/users")
      .then(res => {
        return res.json();
      })
      .then(data => {
        console.log("data", data);
        this.setState({ results: data });
      });
  }

  handleReferences = id => {
    console.log("handleReferences", id);
    const results = fetch(id)
      .then(res => {
        return res.json();
      })
      .then(data => {
        return this.setState({ repos: data });
      })
      .catch(err => console.log(err));
  };
```

Map through to display:

```
  {repos.map((repo, index) => {
          return (
            value === index && (
              <TabContainer key={repo.node_id}>
                <Typography variant="h6">Name: {repo.owner.login} </Typography>
                <Typography> Forks: {tag.forks} </Typography>
              </TabContainer>
            )
          );
        })}
```

JSON sample:

```
[
{
    "id": 26899533,
    "node_id": "MDEwOlJlcG9zaXRvcnkyNjg5OTUzMw==",
    "name": "30daysoflaptops.github.io",
    "full_name": "mojombo/30daysoflaptops.github.io",
    "private": false,
    "owner": {
      "login": "mojombo",
      "id": 1,
      "node_id": "MDQ6VXNlcjE=",
      "avatar_url": "https://avatars0.githubusercontent.com/u/1?v=4",
      "gravatar_id": "",
      "url": "https://api.github.com/users/mojombo",
      "html_url": "https://github.com/mojombo",
      "followers_url": "https://api.github.com/users/mojombo/followers",
      "following_url": "https://api.github.com/users/mojombo/following{/other_user}",
      "gists_url": "https://api.github.com/users/mojombo/gists{/gist_id}",
      "starred_url": "https://api.github.com/users/mojombo/starred{/owner}{/repo}",
      "subscriptions_url": "https://api.github.com/users/mojombo/subscriptions",
      "organizations_url": "https://api.github.com/users/mojombo/orgs",
      "repos_url": "https://api.github.com/users/mojombo/repos",
      "events_url": "https://api.github.com/users/mojombo/events{/privacy}",
      "received_events_url": "https://api.github.com/users/mojombo/received_events",
      "type": "User",
      "site_admin": false
    }
]
```

Thank you so much!!

Comment: It seems to work well on your full code. Could you tell me exactly what the issue is?

Comment: When I tried to get `repo.owner.login` will show `undefined`, I tried to add this 
`if( !repo ){return null }`  before return for async issue, still not working. Thank you.

Comment: Did you check that on code sandbox that you provided? If you didn't, please check. It absolutely works well.